# Need Help Speeding Up Django and DRF with Celery TaskResult Table

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am currently working on an application that utilizes Django, Django Rest Framework (DRF), and Celery, with React in the frontend. I've been encountering a significant performance issue where loading the task results through the DRF API takes more than 10 seconds, as indicated by the debug toolbar. This issue becomes even more pronounced when multiple users attempt to access and display task results concurrently, leading to an API slowdown. In some cases, after sending around 10-15 such requests, my API becomes unresponsive for up to a minute and that causes error 499 in my nginx container making the app unusable for a minute or two.

To provide some context, I am using the get_task_result_info function to update my custom SpiderTaskResult model. I've had to introduce additional fields to the default Celery TaskResult model to support the specific requirements of my Celery tasks.

Here are the steps I've taken thus far to address the issue:

**Actions Taken:**

1. Implemented pagination in React to display a limited number of items (10 per page) in the APIView. While this approach has improved performance somewhat, it required some refactoring in the React code.
2. Experimented with using Django's JsonResponse instead of a typical DRF APIView, but the results remained largely unchanged.
3. I am considering implementing caching however, the task results page receives updates every hour due to a high volume of Celery task execution, resulting in the continuous addition of new task result records. I'm unsure whether caching would be a suitable solution in this scenario and would appreciate guidance on this matter.
4. Implemented select_related and prefetch_related methods to optimize query.

utils.py

```
def get_task_result_info(task_id):
    task_info = SpiderTaskResult.objects.filter(task_id=task_id)
    if task_info:
        return {
            "user_email": task_info[0].user.email,
            "spider_name": task_info[0].spider.name,
            "project_name": task_info[0].spider.project.name,
            "mongodb_database": task_info[0].mongodb_database,
            "mongodb_collection": task_info[0].mongodb_collection
        }
    return {}
```

serializers.py

```
class TaskResultSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    crontab_string = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    
    class Meta:
        model = TaskResult
        fields = '__all__'


    def get_crontab_string(self, instance):
        if instance.periodic_task_name and "oneoff" in instance.periodic_task_name:
            return "oneoff"
        else:
            task = PeriodicTask.objects.filter(name=instance.periodic_task_name)
            if task:
                return get_crontab_string(task[0].crontab)

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        response = super().to_representation(instance)
        response.update(get_task_result_info(instance.task_id))
        return response
```

views.py - with prefetch related (no difference at all)

```
class TaskResultListView(ListAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    serializer_class = TaskResultSerializer
    pagination_class = CustomPagination

    def get_queryset(self):
        spider_id = self.request.GET.get("spider_id")
        user = self.request.user
        queryset = SpiderTaskResult.objects.filter(user=user)
        related_spider = Prefetch(
            'spider',
            queryset=Spider.objects.all().select_related('project', 'spider_config_file', 'yaml_config_file', 'template_file', 'mongodb_collection').only('name', 'project__name', 'spider_config_file__name', 'yaml_config_file__name', 'template_file__name', 'mongodb_collection__name', 'page_type', 'fields_to_scrape', 'kwargs'),
            to_attr='related_spider'
        )
        queryset = queryset.prefetch_related(related_spider)
        if spider_id:
            queryset = queryset.filter(spider_id=spider_id)
        task_results = TaskResult.objects.filter(task_id__in=queryset.values_list('task_id', flat=True)).order_by('-date_done')

        return task_results
```

views.py - without prefetch_related

```
class TaskResultListView(ListAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    serializer_class = TaskResultSerializer
    pagination_class = CustomPagination

    def get_queryset(self):
        spider_id = self.request.GET.get("spider_id")
        user = self.request.user

        # Filter spiders based on user and shared projects
        spiders = Spider.objects.filter(
            Q(user=user) | (Q(project__is_shared=True, project__group__in=user.groups.all()))
        ).distinct().order_by('project__name', 'name')

        # Get the task_ids of relevant SpiderTaskResults
        if spider_id:
            task_ids = SpiderTaskResult.objects.filter(spider_id=spider_id).values_list('task_id', flat=True)
        else:
            task_ids = SpiderTaskResult.objects.filter(spider_id__in=spiders).values_list('task_id', flat=True)

        # Fetch TaskResult objects with a single query
        queryset = TaskResult.objects.filter(task_id__in=task_ids).order_by('-date_done')

        return queryset
```

**Question**

I could really use some guidance here. Could you take a peek at my code and help me figure out how to make it faster? I'm looking at a future where this table will be stuffed with thousands of records, and I want to tackle this problem head-on. Your tips and ideas would be gold to me. Thanks!

Comment: [Look at the raw queries](https://www.neilwithdata.com/django-sql-logging) .  Profile the python code.  If you are hitting the n+1 problem, do look at select_related and prefetch_related.